# Proper way to call a found executable in a custom command?

Tags: cmake

I have a program on my computer, let's say `C:/Tools/generate_v23_debug.exe`

I have a FindGenerate.cmake file which allows CMake to find that exact path to the executable.

So in my CMake code, I do:

```
find_program(Generate)
if (NOT Generate_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Generator not found!")
```

So CMake has found the executable.  Now I want to call this program in a custom command statement.  Should I use `COMMAND Generator` or `COMMAND ${GENERATOR_EXECUTABLE}`?  Will both of these do the same thing?  Is one preferred over the other?  Is name_EXECUTABLE a variable that CMake will define (it's not in the FindGenerate.cmake file), or is it something specific to someone else's example code I'm looking at?  Will `COMMAND Generator` be expanded to the correct path?

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT blahblah.txt
    COMMAND Generator inputfile1.log
    DEPENDS Generator
)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`find_program`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_program) stores its result into the variable given as a first argument. You can verify this by inserting some debug output:

```
find_program(GENERATOR Generate)
message(${GENERATOR})
```

Note that `find_program` does *not* set any additional variables beyond that. In particular, you mentioned `Generate_FOUND` and `GENERATOR_EXECUTABLE` in your question and neither of those gets introduced implicitly by the `find_program` call.

The second mistake in your program is the use of the `DEPENDS` option on the `add_custom_command`. `DEPENDS` is used to model inter-target dependencies at build time and not to manipulate control flow in the CMakeLists. For example, additional custom command can `DEPEND` on the output of your command (`blahblah.txt`), but a custom command cannot `DEPEND` on the result of a previous find operation.

A working example might look something like this:

```
find_program(GENERATOR Generate)
if(NOT GENERATOR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Generator not found!")
endif()

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT blahblah.txt
    COMMAND ${GENERATOR} inputfile1.log
)
```

P.S.: You asked why the code examples were not properly formatted in your question. You indented everything correctly, but you need an additional newline between normal text and code paragraphs. I edited your question accordingly.